# How do you remove html tags using Universal Feed Parser?

Tags: python, django, feed, parsing

The documentation lists the tags that are allowed/removed by default:

http://www.feedparser.org/docs/html-sanitization.html

But it doesn't say anything about how you can specify which additional tags you want removed.

Is there a way to do this using Universal Feed Parser or do you have to do further processing using your own regex and/or something like Beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i took a quick look over the code and i don't think there is a way to overwrite them directly. But you can overwrite `feedparser._HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements`, the list of tags that wont get removed before doing `feedparser.parse`